# React State update asynchronous issue

Tags: reactjs, state

I have this component which creates row data for a table. It sets state. It also creates a button for one of the row states, which contains a reference to a function. I want the state to be available to that button. But it is one request behind. The state available in the showJourneyDetails function is always the previous state to the current state. I know react state is asynchronous so how do I make the current state available inside the showJourneyDetails function?

```
  const [suspected, setSuspectedData] = useState([]);
  const [suspectedReads, setSuspectedReads] = useState(false);

  const findVehiclesOfInterestBetweenDateRange = () => {
      fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/vehicles`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((vehicles) => {

          const suspectedDataReads = vehicles.map((row) => {
            return {
              journey_id: row.journey_id,
              reads: row.reads,
            };
          });
          setSuspectedReads(suspectedDataReads);

          const suspected = vehicles.map((row) => {
            return {
              vrm: row.vrm,
              start_time: row.start_time,
              end_time: row.end_time,
              journey_size: row.journey_size,
              journey_time: row.journey_time,
              score: row.score,
              details: (<Button
                variant="contained"
                onClick={showJourneyDetails}
                id={row.journey_id}
              >
                Details
              </Button>),
            };
          });
          setSuspectedData(suspected);

        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  };

  const showJourneyDetails = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.id);
    console.log("showJourneyDetails suspectedDataReads:", suspectedDataReads);
  }
```

Comment: Can you show us the whole component for context?

Comment: I bet if you wrapped `showJourneyDetails` in `useCallback`, and put `suspectedDataReads` within its dependency array, you would get the most recent value.

Comment: Yes I've updated the code.

Comment: @skellertor using useCallback didn't do the trick unfortunately.